# hide tooltip on a specific value in jQuery pips range slider

Tags: jquery, slider, range

I am working on a range slider. There are two tooltips with values 0 and 5. I want to only show tooltips on other values and hide on these two values. These are actually empty values but are showing as numeric.

My slider is defined as:

```
var $slidern5 = $("#memory-slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
```

but I'm not show how to hide 0 and 5.

See this link: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadaniTech/Lh6pygef/104/)

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking. What kind of answer are you hoping for?

Comment: actually im wishing to hide tooltip on both ends in slider. tooltip should work between the slider on values.

Comment: You can see this link: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadaniTech/Lh6pygef/104/)